# Deploy Web App Linux starts in Container even publishing model is code

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-web-app-for-containers

I deployed .net core 6 project in Web App(Linux, which is up and running and when I see the log stream, I can see below logs

[image: Log Stream Logs]

when I created the Web App(f1) used following Properties

1. Publishing model- "Code"
2. Runtime Stack = "Dotnetcore - 6.0"
3. Operating System = "Linux"

Even as I selected "Code" instead of Container, why Web App running in container ? What's the difference between selection "Code" and "Container" as Publishing model.

And Kudo also showing "This site can’t be reached ERR_TIMED_OUT",

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure App Service for Linux ***by default uses Linux container*** to host the web apps, hence those container logs can be seen in Log stream. It won't be same with windows web apps.

***Windows:***

[image]

> What's the difference between selection "Code" and "Container" as Publishing model.

**1. Publish mode: *Code***

- When you choose "Code" as publish mode, App service will expect you to deploy your code.
- Hence, it provides runtime stack (such as Node.js, .NET, Python, etc.) to choose as per our requirement, and it will execute the code within that particular runtime environment.
- It takes complete control of managing the infrastructure to run the code, so we just have to deploy our code.

**2. Publish mode: *Container***

- When you choose "Container" as the publish mode, we have to deploy pre-built Docker image of our application (with the complete code, packages and the configuration) to the web app.
- It gives flexibility and control over the runtime environment.
- This mode can be used when we want to deploy a pre-configured containerized application and need specific runtime stacks.

***When you deploy web app choosing *code* as *publish* mode,
you can see deployment logs and status in deployment center=>logs:***

[image]

[image]

***When you select *Container* as *publish* mode, the logs will be as shown below:***

[image]

As it can be seen in your logs, it couldn't find the manifest file.

[image]

To resolve this,

- Re-Deploy your web app and try to run again.
- Add port setting before running the web app, Go to App Aervice=>Settings =>Configuration=> Add Application settings=> Name=`WEBSITES_PORT` & value=`8080`.